# navigate through the form by clicking TAB in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have custom DDL. When I navigate through the form by clicking TAB and focus to this DDL, I select item and press TAB but I can't go to the next element of the form. Focus goes to this DDL again but not to the next element. This issue is reproduced in IE, in other browsers it works well.

You can check simple example. The DDL without its styles and some logic there. The order of elements and number can be different in the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/sk8LG/12/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I just took out the bit that checks for keyCode == "9", which is the tab key.

http://jsfiddle.net/sk8LG/13/

Comment: By clicking TAB I want select item and go next element. Thats why I need checks for keyCode == "9". The issue is -  focus goes to this DDL again but not to the next element.